# array_search returns just 1 result

Tags: arrays

I´m starting to study PHP and I have a doubt in one lesson about array_search.

The teachers example shows "A peeple who got a 10" and as only one of the people got a 10 everything works fine, showing the person's name.

But I've been trying to use it to fetch more than one result. In this case I created this array, with 3 people taking 10:

```
    $notas2=array(
    "Ana"=>4,
    "Misca"=>10,
    "Chatuba"=>6,
    "Jurandir"=>7,
    "Musca"=>10,
    "Mickey Mouse"=>10,
);

echo array_search(10,$notas2);
```

This code just returns "Misca". I tried a foreach, but it returned only "MiscaMiscaMiscaMiscaMiscaMisca". lol

```
   foreach(array_search(10,$notas2)as $tirou10){
    echo $tirou10;
}
```

Anyone can help-me?

Tanks.

Comment: The documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) says it returns the *first* corresponding key. So you cannot use it to fetch mulitple results

Comment: Did any of the comments or answers solve your issue? If an answer helped, you can say thanks by checking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` will export only first corresponding key. If you want to get all people who got 10 use `array_keys($notas2, 10)` it will return array and instead of `echo` use `var_dump()` or `var_export()`

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) only returns the first entry.